# Issues Grabbing Entry Via Date

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So I have an entry in the DB.

```
article = BlogPost.objects.get(id=1)
```

I can successfully verify the date of it via day, month and year

```
article.game_date.day = 26
article.game_date.month = 11
article.game_date.year = 2015
```

When I run a query to get this entry:

```
from datetime import date

todays_date = date.today()
articles2 = BlogPost.objects.get(game_date__year = todays_date.year, game_date__month = todays_date.month, game_date__day = todays_date.day)
```

It finds nothing.  However when I run :

```
articles2 = BlogPost.objects.get(game_date__year = todays_date.year)
```

It does find it. But If I run:

```
articles2 = BlogPost.objects.get(game_date__day = todays_date.day)
```

or

```
articles2 = BlogPost.objects.get(game_date__day = 26)
```

It wont find it.  It was working for a bit, but I can't figure out why it did this all of a sudden.

Comment: Is `game_date` a `DateField` or a `DateTimeField`? Is timezone support enabled? What do you get when you print `article.game_date`?

Comment: @Alasdair it is a DateTimeField

Comment: Could be a timezone issue then. What does `todays_date.day` print?

Comment: @Alasdair it prints 26.  If it was a time zone issue the month would work as well.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but why are you breaking the date down to its inidividual components? Why not do `articles2 = BlogPost.objects.get(game_date=todays_date)`?

Comment: @Pynchia because `game_date` is a `DateTimeField`, it has a time component as well as a date.

Comment: sorry, I haven't noticed the comment above

Comment: How did you verify article.game_date.day was equal to 26? In the shell? Also, how are you assigning the date to the object?

Comment: @IsaacRay Yes i did that in the shell, also ran a "article.game_date.day == todays_date.day" and it came out as true

Comment: Checked what value is being stored in the database, e.g. `select * from myapp_article`.

Comment: @Alasdair 2015-11-26 10:45:21

Comment: I also have some other datetimefields and tried to query them via month/day and had the same issue, but again the year worked.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks anyways @Alasdair